# Fixing Old Leaky Faucet - Handles won't budge

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, leak, faucet

I've been tolerating a small leak for a while in our bathroom, but it's started to get bad enough that it needs fixing.

While I was hoping I could just pop out the handles and replace an old O-ring or set washer, I can't for the life of me figure out a safe way to remove the handles. The handles are missing the screws, & won't budge with force.

Here's a picture of the faucet type and a detailed pic of the handle:

[image: Bathroom Faucet Full]
[image: Bathroom Faucet Detail]

There is no cold/hot shutoff in the room (I'm guessing it's under the house, not easily accessible), so I'm not really sure which handle I'd need to tighten up/replace parts for yet. I have easy access to shut off the main water supply in the event I need to start cutting things off.

Suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you sure they're missing the screws? They would most likely be set-screws (flat or hex) inside those holes but it is difficult to see in the picture for sure. Without screws, the handles should just pull straight up. Yes, they may be tight but should still come off. Before pulling out the valves or cartridges (most likely), I would definitely suggest turning off the water source.

Comment: Actually, it looks like there might be screws after all! Turns out even after researching I didn't realize the screws had an insert in them - I sprayed some oil down the hole & what looked like just a stripped set has a hex key at the very back. D'oh

Comment: Despite having 20 hex keys, none fit - I've ordered the part & will test in a few days